# Ajax call for XML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am expecting this to be successful but it isn't working, I don't see the alert.

```
function insertXML()
{
    $.ajax ({
        url: 'cd_catalog.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(  )
        {           
            alert('called');
        }
    });
}
```

cd_catalog.xml is in the same directory as the javascript executing the code and is named correctly.

This is an exact copy paste from code I used for login queries as well, am I messing up something here?

jquery-1.7.1.min.js is imported in the head as well, and the script containing the code is being executed in the body.

Comment: Do you see any error in the log console?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Thinking I may test this on my local apache server then.

Comment: ajax-calls don't work on local filesystem in most browsers, where do you run this?

Comment: Yeah I ran this locally, I completely forgot you have to make ajax calls from an actual server address. Very sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you make Ajax calls to a web server and not to a local file.

Comment: yes. you are right. I just missed the comments from the question. anyway at least you can refer to in-depth description so I can cancel my down vote :)